# When locking a sheet, the VB Code stops working

Tags: vb.net, excel, worksheet

Here is my code; when I lock the sheet the code stops working and will not pop up on the double click.

On another note is there a way to activate the code without requiring it to double click?

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
End Sub

```
'==========================
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, _
  Cancel As Boolean)
Dim str As String
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("NameBox")
  On Error Resume Next
  With cboTemp
  'clear and hide the combo box
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
  End With
On Error GoTo errHandler
  If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    'if the cell contains a data validation list
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'get the data validation formula
    str = Target.Validation.Formula1
    str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
    With cboTemp
      'show the combobox with the list
      .Visible = True
      .Left = Target.Left
      .Top = Target.Top
      .Width = Target.Width + 5
      .Height = Target.Height + 5
      .ListFillRange = str
      .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    End With
    cboTemp.Activate
    'open the drop down list automatically
    Me.NameBox.DropDown

  End If

errHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub
'=========================================
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim str As String
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Application.CutCopyMode Then
  'allow copying and pasting on the worksheet
  GoTo errHandler
End If

Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("NameBox")
  On Error Resume Next
  With cboTemp
    .Top = 10
    .Left = 10
    .Width = 0
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
    .Value = ""
  End With

errHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub
'====================================
'Optional code to move to next cell if Tab or Enter are pressed
'from code by Ted Lanham
'***NOTE: if KeyDown causes problems, change to KeyUp

Private Sub NameBox_KeyDown(ByVal _
        KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
        ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9 'Tab
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case 13 'Enter
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
'====================================
```

Comment: By "Lock" the sheet do you mean protect?

Comment: Yes sorry; protecting locked cells causes the VB Code to not run